# How can I prevent the same string from being added into my stored array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

My tableViewCell stores an array of strings. Every time I enter a new string after pressing a button, it is added into that array. But, I do not want the same String to be added twice into this array. How can I prevent them from being added? I also want an alert message to appear when duplication occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better yet use an `NSMutableOrderedSet` instead of an array. An ordered set can contain only one entry for a given object. If you try to add the same object twice, nothing happens, so you won't need any custom code.

I don't know if Swift has an ordered set class yet. I'm not aware of one, but the Cocoa Foundation classes are fully usable from Swift.

### EDIT:

A quick google search revealed a [**3rd party Swift ordered set class**](http://www.magicalpenguin.com/blog/introducing-a-swift-orderedset). I haven't used it but it sounds promising from the description.

Answer (score 0):

Before adding any object to `array` check if `array` already contains that object like following

```
if([yourArray containsObject:@"xyz"]){
     // show alert
}
else{
  [yourArray addObject:@"xyz"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `if`  & `else` and put a check in `if`- that the entered element exists into it or not `else` enter that element into your array :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
- (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender
{
  if([arr_of_Strings containsObject:yourTextField.text])
{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ERROR" 
                                                    message:@"Same Element" 
                                                    delegate:self 
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                                    otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
else
{
  [arr_of_Strings addObject:yourTextField.text];
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check if the element is present in the array or not

Here is the example .

```
if (yourArray.contains(aStr!)) { 
   let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Warning", message: "This String is already in your array", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: nil, otherButtonTitles: "OK", nil)
   alert.show()
}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the words is not relevant you should use a `Set`.

A `Set` in Swift is a `Struct` that cannot contain more that one instance of the same value.

Here it is a code snipped

```
class Foo {
    var words = Set<String>()

    func add(word:String) {
        if words.contains(word) {
            showMessageToUser()
        } else {
            words.insert(word)
        }
    }

    func showMessageToUser() {
        // ....
    }
}
```